# Schur outputs from LAPACK not matching MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, lapack, lapacke

I am trying to reproduce the schur function using LAPACK, but am facing difficulty in getting results to match MATLAB, despite the fact that MATLAB internally uses LAPACK for its schur. I tried using LAPACK_dgehrd and LAPACK_dhseqr, however the last column of T doesn't match MATLAB. I then tried using dgees, however the ordering of the eigen values in the matrix T is different than that given by MATLAB, which in turn causes the rest of the T matrix to differ. I have inserted the C code I was using for LAPACK. The dgehrd and dhesqr portion is commented. Also attached is an image, with the results for a small 4x4 matrix using three ways:

1. MATLAB
2. dgehrd&dhesqr
3. dgees

The MATLAB function I was using was very simple: [Q,T]=schur(A);

Please note that when I use dgehrd and dhesqr, the outputs do not even satisfy the U*T*U'=A condition of schur; while the dgees and MATLAB outputs satisfy that.

Could you please guide me as to what I am doing wrong with using dgehrd&dhesqr that caused only the last column of T to be incorrect? I have tried using dgebal before LAPACK_dgehrd and LAPACK_dorghr before LAPACK_dhseqr, but that didn't help either.  Also, I tried using the sort "S" option with dgees using the lapack_logical function at the end of the C code, setting sdim to nrows-1 and; but that was causing a crash, could you guide me as to where I am going wrong with that?

[image: schur comparison from MATLAB and two LAPACK packages]

```
#include "lapacke.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifndef free_NULL
    #define free_NULL(T) {free(T); T = NULL;}
#endif

int schur(double *val, int nrows, double *U, double *T)
{
    int i, j, lwork = -1;
    int info;
    int sdim = 0;//nrows-1;//
    int ilo = 1, ihi = nrows -1;
    double *tau = NULL;
    double wkopt;
    double *wr = NULL, *wi = NULL, *Z = NULL;
    double  *work = NULL;
    extern LAPACK_D_SELECT2          SELECT;
    lapack_logical    *bwork;
    FILE *file = NULL;  
    file = fopen("Schurpack.csv","w");
    wr = (double *)calloc(nrows,sizeof(double));
    wi = (double *)calloc(nrows,sizeof(double));
    Z  = (double *)calloc(nrows*nrows,sizeof(double));
    bwork  = (lapack_logical *)calloc(nrows,sizeof(lapack_logical));

    LAPACK_dgees ( "V", "N", SELECT, &nrows, val, &nrows, &sdim, wr, wi, Z, &nrows, &wkopt, &lwork, bwork, &info ); 
    lwork = (int)wkopt;
    work = (double*)malloc( lwork*sizeof(double) );
    LAPACK_dgees ( "V", "N", SELECT, &nrows, val, &nrows, &sdim, wr, wi, Z, &nrows, work, &lwork, bwork, &info ); 


    //tau = (double *)calloc(nrows-1,sizeof(double));
    //lwork = -1; 
    //LAPACK_dgehrd( &nrows, &ilo, &ihi, val, &nrows, tau, &wkopt, &lwork, &info);
    //
    //lwork = (int)wkopt;
    //work = (double *)calloc(lwork,sizeof(double));
    //LAPACK_dgehrd( &nrows, &ilo, &ihi, val, &nrows, tau, work, &lwork, &info);

    //lwork = nrows;
    //work = (double *)calloc(nrows,sizeof(double));
    //LAPACK_dhseqr ( "S", "I", &nrows, &ilo, &ihi, val, &nrows, wr, wi, Z, &nrows, work, &lwork, &info );   
    if( info > 0 ) 
    {
        printf( "The algorithm computing Schur Decompsition failed to converge.\n" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    for( i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < nrows; j++)
        { 
            U[i*nrows+j] = Z[j*nrows+i];
            T[i*nrows+j] = val[j*nrows+i];
        }
    }

    fprintf(file, "U\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j < nrows; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
            fprintf(file,"%f,",U[j*(nrows)+i]);
        fprintf(file,"\n");
    }


    fprintf(file,"T\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j < nrows; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
            fprintf(file,"%f,",T[j*(nrows)+i]);
        fprintf(file,"\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    file = NULL;


    if (tau)
        free_NULL(tau);
    if (wr)
        free_NULL(wr);
    if (wi)
        free_NULL(wi);
    if (Z)
        free_NULL(Z);
    if (work)
        free_NULL(work);

    return(0);
}


lapack_logical SELECT ( double ER, double EI)
{
    if ((ER==1) && (EI==0))
        return(0);
    else
        return(1);
}
```

Comment: When using `gees` you have to use the same ordering criterion and then supply `S` for the `SORT` keyword. Then they should match

Comment: I think generally you should provide your input as ascii and not as screenshot, so everyone can copy&paste easily.